# Blender is lagging when sculpting with dyntopo from 2.00 detail onwards

Tags: sculpt

I started following a sculpting tutorial, and they said to turn on Dyntopo in constant detail at 10, but it lags really badly, it starts lagging with detail at 2.

My system details on blender are [image: system blender details]

I have seen what happens in the log and there is a spike in cpu but it shouldnt cause this problem.

Are there any system preferences I should change to get a better performance

Comment: How big is your model (dimensions)? Have you applied the scale? ('Ctrl'+'A' in *Object* mode) How many vertices has it? It could be that you have too many vertices that cause the lag. Enable the *Statistics* and the *Wireframe* overlays to get an overview. As an alternative to Dyntopo, you can try whether you achieve better performance with the Voxel Remesher ('R' to see the voxel size, 'Ctrl'+'R' to remesh or use the drop-down menu right next to Dyntopo)

Comment: The model has x:111mm y:24.6mm z:3.42mm, I have applied the scale. Vertices:560, edges:1.674, faces:1,116 and triangles:1.116. As i'm a new learner with sculpting i'm following different tutorials and this one is working with dyntopo, I want to learn all the different ways to see which one I prefer.

Comment: I've tried Dyntopo on a cube with the same size. But then I have to increase the resolution to 200, otherwise there is not enough vertices left to create the cube model.

Comment: But if it's lagging at 10 with not much resolution won't it lag more with 200 resolution? Sorry if it's a dumb question

Comment: Yes, it would create more vertices and lag even more. But it's odd and it makes no sense that it lags with 2 resolution. That's very low-poly. Have you tried with the default cube? This is how 3, 5, 20, and 50 resolution looks on the default cube (6,747 verts, 13,490 triangles): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3J7CY.jpg. (There is no lag, tested on a laptop with integrated graphics, Blender 3.6.0). If you can share a demo file we can try, too.

Comment: Yeah, with a cube it works fine after I remesh it and it starts lagging with dyno at 9.00 detail

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, found out what I was doing wrong, as I mostly use blender for precise modeling I was working in mm instead of meters, so even 2.00 was to much resolution, now I can use Dyno at 10 with no problems.